# I have a problem with strings in C, declared as follows: char * s = "hello";

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm studying strings and pointers in C.
From what I have studied, I understand that if I write:

```
char * s = "hello";
```

I am creating a 6 character / 6 byte array and making char * s point to this newly created array In the example above I create two strings a and b:

```
char a [20];
char b [20];
```

and then two pointers s and s2 pointing to a and b:

```
char * s = a;
char * s2 = b;
```

If I write:

```
if (s == s2)
```

I get printed False on screen, because, ACCORDING TO MY LOGIC, I am comparing if email
pointed to by s is equal to what s2 is pointing to. So far I have understood everything.
Now the part that I didn't understand. If instead of creating two strings and assigning addresses to
pointers, I wrote:

```
char * s = "hello";
char * s2 = "hello";
if (s == s2)
```

I am printed True.
I don't understand why. This second conditional statement shouldn't compare whether to use
is pointed by s equal to what s2 is pointing to?
I expected False to be printed again. Help !!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    {
        char a[20] = "hello";
        char b[20] = "hello";
        char *s = a;
        char *s2 = b;

        if(s == s2)//address of s == address of s2 ? False
        {
           printf("True\n");
        } 
        else
        {
           printf("False\n");
        }
    }

    //if i try to do :

    char *s = "hello";
    char *s2 = "hello";

    if(s == s2)//the result is True, but i don't understood because.
    { 
       printf("True\n");
    }
    else
    {
       printf("False\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a` and `b` have probably been optimized by your compiler to point to 1 piece of memory

Comment: Identical string literals might or might not be the same literal in the memory. You can't rely on either behavior.

Comment: Identical string literals are very commonly optimized by the compiler to only get stored in one single location, something called "string pooling". (gcc `-fmerge-constants` (default) vs `-fno-merge-constants` if I remember correctly)

Comment: Multiple occurrences of a string literal *may* map to a single instance in memory.

Comment: Hei guys then, after the instructions:

    char * s = "hello";
    char * s2 = "hello";

Istruction:

if (s == s2)

it is comparing memory addresses that are most likely identical because the compiler has made s and s2 point to the same memory area.
Am I right?